# writing a static value returning method called max

Tags: methods

My assignment is: Write a static value returning method called max that has two int parameters, num1 and num2, and returns the larger of the two integers.

i just dont know what to write for the method

```
 // variable declarations 
 int number1;
 int number2;
 // user prompts 
 System.out.print("Enter first number:");
 number1 = in.nextInt();
 System.out.print("Enter second number:");
 number2 = in.nextInt();
 // call the method for part 2 inside the println statement
 System.out.println("The largest number is " + max(number1, number2));
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: {
if(num1 > num2) return num1; else return num2;
   }

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: where do i put that in the code? im getting an error when i type that in

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment tells you to create a static method. A static method
has the word `static` in the signature. Example:

```
public static
```

The next thing you need to specify is the return type, which in this case is an integer:

```
public static int
```

The assignment already describes the name and parameters of the method:

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
```

Now: write the complete method with the content as you have already written, and place it **within** the class of yours, but **outside** the main method:

```
...
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
    if(num1 > num2) return num1; else return num2;
}
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* I assume your code is taken from the main method */
}
```